# A good way to use facial landmarks as input

Tags: deep-learning, vision, keypoint

We are planning to use facial landmark information as input to the model. Since there are more than 60 points, it doesn't look good to use 60 channels as inputs after one-hot encoding. I found a few papers with similar ideas, but I didn't like it. What is the exact name of this methodology, and is there a well-known good way?

Comment: Hi this question is more suitable for the [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I didn't know there was such a site. Thanks.